# Render different components on client and server side

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am currently developing a website where I have used react, react-router and redux. We are doing Server side rendering and using react router on server as well. Now I have a case where i want client side to render different component than server side. I want like this.

Client Side

```
<Route path="welcome/:id" component={Home} />
```

Server Side

```
<Route path="welcome/:id" component={App} />
```

I have use case like when user click's an image i want to open a modal with contents and recommend images . when user click's on recommended images same modal should fill up the details and i want to change the route as well. Same route when opened in new window should open an html page for facebook and google to scrap meta tags from it.

So either I render different component on client and server. But that too has a problem because then i need to find a way to turn off client side react router when server is serving the rendered page.

Or in client side generate a pseudo route change which changes url but doesn't render a component.

Comment: Hey @Priyank Bhatt did you find a way to accomplish with this?

Comment: Yup I got the solution but it's mostly a hack. So what i did is. I remove all the contents from window.intial__state  whenever their are contents in it. And by using react-router getComponent i checked whether the window.intial__state is empty if it is then routing is triggered from client side so render that component. And If window__intialstate is not empty then render other Component.
<pre><code> function onUpdate() {
  if (window.__INITIAL_STATE__ !== null) {
    window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = null;
    return;
  }
}</code></pre>

Comment: `function onUpdate() {
  if (window.__INITIAL_STATE__ !== null) {
    window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = null;
    return;
  }
}`

Comment: `<Router history={history} onUpdate={onUpdate}>`

Answer (score 3):

Check if `window` is present and conditionally set the component you want to use like this:

```
let Handler;

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  Handler = Home;
} else {
  Handler = App;
}

return <Route path="welcome/:id" component={Handler} />
```

The troublemaker in me wants to know why you're doing this :)

Comment: I have use case like when user click's an image i want to open a modal with contents and recommend images . when user click's on recommended images same modal should fill up the details and i want to change the route as well. Same route when opened in new window should open an html page for facebook and google to scrap meta tags from it.

Comment: But i dont think so this would be useful because every time a server rendered pages is served client again checks for the route in react router and it will render modal instead of html page.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah not sure then, sounds like an odd way to go about it. What would happen if the user refreshed the page? They'd see something completely different? Maybe outline the desired behaviour in the question.

Comment: yup if user refreshed the page they would see same content without modal in html page . So probably i would want something like pseudo route change on client side.

Answer (score 1):

check process.env.Browser

```
let Handler;

if (process.env.browser) {
  Handler = Home;
} else {
  Handler = App;
}

return <Route path="welcome/:id" component={Handler} />
```

Comment: This solution will not work. please read the use case . When server send's the render page, client side react router again check for the url and render's client side component. So always client side component will be rendered. I need a way to bypass client side react router if server is serving the page only then this solution can work.